# Open or closed set or neither

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Can somebody explain me why the following set in neither open nor closed.

$$ B:=\{ (x,y)\in \mathbb Q^2: 1\le x,y\le 10 \}$$

My thoughts:- If I can find an $\epsilon$ neighborhood that belongs to the set at every point in the set then it is open.  If the complement set of the set is open then the set is closed.

Comment: It might be easier to work with the sequential definitions.

Comment: $B$ is a closed subset of $\Bbb Q^2$, but not of $\Bbb R^2$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $(x,y) \in B$ and $U$ a $ \epsilon$ - neighborhood of $(x,y)$. Then $U$ contains infinitely many points $(a,b)$ with $(a,b) \notin \mathbb Q^2$. So, no $ \epsilon$ - neighborhood of $(x,y)$ is contained in $B$. Therefore $B$ is not open.

We have $ \overline{B}=\{ (x,y)\in \mathbb R^2: 1\le x,y\le 10 \}$, hence $B \ne \overline{B}$ and $B$ is not closed.